# Create report in ASPX.NET by passing value?

Tags: asp.net

Can you please direct me to a tutorial or other resource for accomplishing the following:

Index page lists 50 states. Onlick of a state Y, the report page (report.aspx) will display info related to state Y, pulled from database.mdb, interspersed in HTML text.

I am not even sure what the terms and controls I need to be working with.

Thank you.
UncleJune

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know how to create the report? That is the first step. After that it is just a matter of passing the required parameter from one page to the next. Several methods can be used to do this: Response.Redirect/Request.QueryString, session variable, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial might help you:

[Using the ASP.NET 2.0 ReportViewer in Local Mode](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/ReportViewer.aspx)

[Dynamic reports with Microsoft local report engine](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Microsoft_Dynamic_Reports.aspx)

Comment: I found this helpful as well: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydvMHl_73KE